# AG-Grid sorting is not working with TreeData

Tags: sorting, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid with **Tree Data**. (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/).

I am facing an issue that column is being sorted in lexicographical order instead of Asc/Desc. For number columns, it should be sorted by max/min value. Here is the JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pbjqdw6w and see the behavior of **Currency** column.

`enableSorting: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide your own sorting function if you want to override the default behaviour.

Take a look at the [Sorting Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/) for more information, but in a nutshell you need to supply a sorting function on the column in question:

```
colDef.comparator = function (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) {
    return valueA - valueB;
}
```